# Label in Tab Panel Using C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, tabs, label

does anyone know how can I set label generated in C# to be positioned at the center of the tab panel? (Please see below image)

**This is the output i want to achieve:**
[image]
This is my code:

```
if(panel.Controls.Count<1)
                {
                    System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl panelDIV = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
                    panelDIV.ID = "panelDIV";
                    panelDIV.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.TextAlign, "center");
                    panelDIV.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "100%");
                    panelDIV.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Position, "center");
                    panelDIV.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.FontStyle, "Arial");


                    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label newTabel = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label();
                    newTabel.Text +=  "no chart to display";
                    newTabel.Font.Bold = true;
                    newTabel.Font.Size=16;
                    panelDIV.Controls.Add(newTabel);
                    panel.Controls.Add(panelDIV);
                }
```

**Question: how to set label generated in C# to be positioned at the center of the tab panel?**
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample to put the label to center of the page

.aspx

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPanel1" runat="server" Text="Panel 1" OnClick="btnPanel1_Click" />
&nbsp;
<asp:Button ID="btnPanel2" runat="server" Text="Panel 2" OnClick="btnPanel2_Click" />

<br />
<asp:Panel ID="pnl1" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel ID="pnl2" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Panel>
```

.cs

```
protected void btnPanel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!pnl1.HasControls())
    {
        pnl1.Attributes.Add("style", "width: 100%;");

        HtmlGenericControl pnlDiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        pnlDiv.ID = "pnlDiv1";
        pnlDiv.Attributes.Add("style", "width: 100%; text-align:center;");


        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.ID = "lblSomething";
        lbl.Text = "Panel 1 Something";
        lbl.Font.Bold = true;
        lbl.Font.Size = 16;
        lbl.Attributes.Add("style", "position: absolute; top: 50%; bottom: 50%; left: 0; right: 0;");
        pnlDiv.Controls.Add(lbl);
        pnl1.Controls.Add(pnlDiv);
    }
    pnl1.Visible = true;
    pnl2.Visible = false;
}

protected void btnPanel2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!pnl2.HasControls())
    {
        pnl2.Attributes.Add("style", "width: 100%;");

        HtmlGenericControl pnlDiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        pnlDiv.ID = "pnlDiv2";
        pnlDiv.Attributes.Add("style", "width: 100%; text-align:center;");


        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.ID = "lblSomething2";
        lbl.Text = "Panel 2 Something";
        lbl.Font.Bold = true;
        lbl.Font.Size = 16;
        lbl.Attributes.Add("style", "position: absolute; top: 50%; bottom: 50%; left: 0; right: 0;");
        pnlDiv.Controls.Add(lbl);
        pnl2.Controls.Add(pnlDiv);
    }

    pnl1.Visible = false;
    pnl2.Visible = true;
}
```